# Error with get('model').addObjects() in Ember 1.13.0

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm upgrading an Ember application from 1.11 to 1.13.2

I've got a blog initially displaying 5 blog-entries. They are loaded in the model with this route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post', {limit: 5});
   }
});
```

There's a button to load more entries in the controller:

```
loadMore: function() {
  var self = this
  this.store.find('post', {limit: 5,
                           skip: 5})
    .then(function(posts) {
      self.incrementProperty('page');
      self.get('model').addObjects(posts);
    });
}
```

However since upgrading I get this error after `loadMore` was executed:

```
TypeError: internalModel.getRecord is not a function
    at Ember.ArrayProxy.extend.objectAtContent (record-array.js:84)
    at _emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend.objectAt (ember.debug.js:35919)
    at _emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend.objectAtContent (ember.debug.js:35780)
    at _emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend.objectAt (ember.debug.js:35919)
```

Comment: `loadMore` code is in the rote or in the controller?

Comment: It's in the controller

Comment: Ember is in a fever preparing to the 2.0 release. Try upgrading Ember and Ember Data to 1.13.4, this might help.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in Ember Data 1.13.5

Comment: Hey was able to fix a similar issue this with this code: `posts.addObject(post._internalModel)` It is obviously just a single record added and huge hack, but it did fix the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `ember-cli` it comes loaded with babel, might as well use ES6 syntax, load more becomes the following:

```
loadMore() {
  this.store.find('post', {
    limit: 5,
    skip: 5
  })
    .then((posts) => {
      this.incrementProperty('page');
      let model = this.get('model');
      posts.forEach(model.pushObject.bind(model));
    });
}
```

Comment: It sends the correct requests to the server and receives the correct payload but never actually adds the entries to the presentation.

Comment: @Hedge if you log posts what do you get? And can you add your template how are you echoing them out

Comment: I forgot to check the error-log. When hitting `posts.forEach(model.pushObject.bind(model))` I get a `TypeError: internalModel.getRecord is not a function`. console.log(posts)* contains an Ember Object.

Comment: Do you have the project up on github? If it's private are you abel to isolate and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your work but I think I'll go with a cleaner approach by using `ember-infinity` as soon as one required PR is in it.